# getnameinfo prototype asks for sockaddr not sockaddr_in?

Tags: c, sockets, struct, ip, hostname

The getnameinfo prototype asks for `sockaddr` but I have only seen examples using `sockaddr_in`. Can this example be re-written for `sockaddr` ? sin_family becomes `sa_family` but what about sin_port and `sin_addr` ? How are they included in `sa_data` ?

```c
struct sockaddr{
    unsigned short  sa_family;
    char            sa_data[14];
};

struct sockaddr_in{
    short           sin_family;
    unsigned short  sin_port;
    struct in_addr  sin_addr;
    char            sin_zero[8];
};


struct sockaddr_in sin;
memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
sin.sin_family      = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPvar);
sin.sin_port        = 0; // If 0, port is chosen by system

getnameinfo( (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin), buffervar, sizeof(buffervar), NULL, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 5):

`struct sockaddr` is a "super-class" of the concrete protocol address structures like `struct sockaddr_in`, `struct sockaddr_in6`, and `struct sockaddr_un`, etc. The `getnameinfo(3)` dispatches to a specific execution path based of the address family (the `sa_family` member.)

As far as memory is concerned - the three members of `struct sockaddr_in` are *overlaid* with the `struct sockaddr`'s `sa_data` member. Take a look at Chapter 3 of the [UnP book](http://www.unpbook.com/).

Comment: And this is why you have to pass in the size of the address structure that you've given it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But then, why can't you just pass a `void*` since you have the size ?
Why the need for a common type ?

Comment: @cassepipe — I can think of a couple of reasons to avoid `void *`.  First, you lose whatever smidgen of type-safety is available — you could pass any type of pointer to the function and the compiler couldn't complain that the `int *` or `char *` or `struct passwd *` passed to the function is wrong.  The second is probably history — and consistency with history.  However, I wasn't party to the decision-making process and I don't know why the design was chosen.  It wasn't decided casually, however.